Can't create Firestore document with a (blocking) Cloud Function
General
When I use the following cloud function, the creation of Auth users works, but no Firestore document is created.
import { identity } from "firebase-functions/v2";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();

export const createfirestoreuser = identity.beforeUserCreated(async (event) => {
  await firestore.collection("users").doc(event.data.uid).create({
    "id": event.data.uid,
    // TODO: Add defaults
  });
  return;
});

The blocking function is set to createfirestoreuser:

But it seems that the cloud function isn't triggered:


If there is nothing in the function logs that clearly points to your code being the problem, there is not much we can do to help. If you think that the function should trigger, but it does not at all, you should reach out to Firebase support directly.

@DougStevenson As this is my first cloud function, I assume for the time being that the fault probably has to do with something on my end.

If you think the problem is with your code, you need to provide logs or something that indicates what the problem might be.  We can't really help if your only evidence is that it's just not running at all.  Firebase support might be able to help you understand if there is a problem in the system that can be corrected.

Where/How can I get the logs? What else should I post?
